# How exactly does gnome manage laptop suspend events?

Tags: laptop, window-manager, suspend, power-management

The reason I ask is that, while suspend under lid closure and fn-F4 work perfectly in the Ubuntu (gnome) desktop, I cannot get them to work when using a different window manager (fvwm) on my thinkpad X201.  I thought this was taken care of by gnome-power-manager, but
when running gnome-power-manager within fvwm, I get no suspend from lid closure or fn-F4.
I tried starting other processes as well, like gnome-settings-daemon, but this had no effect.  I also tried fiddling with acpi settings, without sucess.

Answer (score 1):

*Answered by OP in a comment:*

> I worked around my problem by declaring `fvwm` as my window manager
>   from within `gnome-session`. This is good because gnome still controls
>   the power management and gets it all right, but not ideal in that fvwm
>   doesn't work perfectly in this environment. I would still like to know
>   how gnome is getting the laptop to suspend under lid closure and
>   <kbd>fn</kbd>-<kbd>F4</kbd> so that I could manage it myself.

Answer (score 0):

I been using the pm-* (power management) tools under xfce4.  Call `sudo pm-suspend` or `sudo pm-hibernate` from a panel button.  I do remember a little hiccup when I upgraded to 10.04, but no issues going to 10.10.

Comment: Sounds like you have to do it all manually then--no suspend on lid closure?  I worked around my problem by declaring fvwm as my window manager from within gnome-session; this is good because gnome still controls the power management and gets it all right, but not ideal in that fvwm doesn't work perfectly in this environment.   I would still like to know how gnome is getting the laptop to suspend under lid closure and fn-F4 so that I could manage it myself.  Why is it such an undocumented secret?  Gnome is getting to be too much like Windows!